# What is the jQuery equivalent for pageYOffset?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
window.pageYOffset
```

What is the jQuery equivalent to `pageYOffset`?

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop()` [ScrollTop vs PageYOffset](https://jsperf.com/window-pageyoffset-vs-jquery-s-scrolltop)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `$(window).scrollTop()`, This returns an integer.

The API documentation is [here](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Comment: What do you mean by this? *...if you are using it in CSS...*

Comment: Well, if you wanted to set the `top` property, you cannot use `.css('top', $(window).scrollTop())`, you need to use `.css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + "px")`

Comment: You don't have to actually, most properties will automatically be parsed as pixels with jQuery...

Answer (score -3):

It returns the pixels the current document has been scrolled from the upper left corner window, horizontally and vertically.

Comment: You appear to have misread the question. It is asking for a jQuery equivalent, not a definition.